# what is the major difference between x86 and x386 registers

Tags: x86, intel, cpu-registers, microprocessors

I am taking Intel Microprocessor course, and reading about microprocessors and registers, I got confused about the difference of registers between microprocessors.

For example, I know that x86 have 8 general purpose registers and the x386DX has a total of 16 registers.

Besides the number of registers, what is the major difference between the two microprocessors registers?

Comment: "x386DX" isn't a thing.  Did you mean 80386DX? 
 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80386#80386DX)  One of the first generation of 32-bit CPUs?  Why are you counting only GP registers for "x86", but all registers (including segment registers, EFLAGS, and EIP) for 386DX?  The FPU is external for 386DX (unlike 486DX), so you can't count the x87 stack registers.  If you're going to count non-GP registers, why not also count control registers?  386 introduced some new ones for virtual memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one other difference could be the x86 contain a 16-bit FLAGS register and the x386 contain a 32-bit extended EFLAGS register.

FLAGS indicate a condition of a microprocessor and its operation.

Answer (score 2):

**Just a little clarification for anyone that passes by**

[x386](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X386) is **not** a CPU but an old window manager for [UNIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix).

[x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) is the [architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) of the entire range of CPUs from the [8086](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086) to the [i686 (P6)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I686), and all their clones and successors.

It is also extended by [x86_64 (AMD64)](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=X86_64) which is [AMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Micro_Devices)'s 64-bit version of [Intel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel)'s x86 architecture. Intel has rebranded these extensions as Intel64 in their own CPUs. Not to be confused with [IA-64 (Itanium)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-64) which is NOT [binary compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-code_compatibility) with x86 (or x86_64) at all.

[i386](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80386) is a generation of x86 CPUs. It was the first x86 CPUs with the [IA-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-32) architecture implemented. It is thus a 32-bit CPU, and it has extensions that make binaries non-backwards compatible, but they will run on any newer x86 CPU. Even on the x86_64 CPUs.

So while binaries compiled for an 8086 should run on almost an x86 CPU, if supported by the OS, they won't take advantage of all the improvements and [extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Extensions).

Here is a list of the most notable [architectural features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-32#Architectural_features) of the i386.

And here are the [registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#x86_registers) (from the same article). Read about the differences from 16-bit to 32-bit.

Comment: `i386` is also used in GNU/Linux software (e.g. Linux `uname -a` output) as a synonym for IA-32, as opposed to AMD64 / x86-64 (which Intel sometimes calls IA-32e as well as Intel64).  Also worth noting that in Windows / MSVC terminology, x86 specifically means 32-bit code, excluding x86-64.  Everyone else knows that x86 does include everything that's backwards compat with 8086, regardless of whether it's running in x86-64 long mode or not.

Comment: The question does mention x386DX, so possibly they're talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80386#80386DX.  But it's still a totally unclear question, because x86 doesn't refer to any specific iteration of the ISA.